# Clojure and JavaFX 2.0 -- How to access element's ID from clojure callback function

Tags: binding, clojure, annotations, javafx-2, fxml

Following the JavaFX Tutorial here: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/fxml_tutorial.htm, trying to make it run in Clojure.  For now I'm just doing `lein run` after setting up `:aot :all` and stuff with `(:gen-class)` etc.  It took a few days of figuring out, but now it seems to be mostly working.

In `src/jfxtwo/ClojureExampleController.clj`:

```
(defn -handleSubmitButtonAction [^ActionEvent event]
  (let [actiontarget (Text.)]
    (println "event button pressed")
    (println "Event instance:" event)
    (println "Event class:" (class event))
    (.setText actiontarget "Sign in button pressed...")))
```

In `resources/fxml_example.fxml`:

```
<GridPane fx:controller= "jfxtwo.ClojureExampleController"
      xmlns:fx= "http://javafx.com/fxml" 
      alignment= "center" hgap= "10" vgap= "10"
      styleClass= "root" >
...
    <Button text= "Sign In"
    onAction= "#handleSubmitButtonAction" />

...
    <Text fx:id= "actiontarget"
        GridPane.columnIndex= "1" GridPane.rowIndex= "6" />
...
```

I have my clojure code able to read the fxml and css file to generate the proper GUI.  When I press the button I can see the event handler being called, but I don't know how to access the `Text` I want to change, or the `ActionEvent` instance that is associated with the button press.  I tried `(println event)` and `(println (class event))` expecting to see something about an `ActionEvent` instance, but this only results in showing me that for whatever reason the callback function thinks the event is a `ClojureExampleController`, even though the type hint says it should be an `ActionEvent`:

```
event button pressed
Event instance: #<ClojureExampleController jfxtwo.ClojureExampleController@3e61061d>
Event class: jfxtwo.ClojureExampleController
```

The Java code to do this looks like this:

```
public class JFXAppSampleController  {
   @FXML private Text actiontarget;
   @FXML protected void handleSubmitButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
       actiontarget.setText("Sign in button pressed");
   }
}
```

Clearle the `@FXML` annotation is doing the magic here.  What's going on, and how do I make this work in Clojure?

Also, is there a way to bind the button press to the text change directly in the FXML so I don't really have to handle a gui->gui change in the code-behind, and instead only deal with the logic associated with the button press?  I'm guessing yes, but I haven't gotten to that point in the tutorial.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an explicit `this` argument in your handler:

```
(defn -handleSubmitButtonAction [this ^ActionEvent event]
  ...)
```

Perhaps a more accurate way of putting this is that `event` *is* the `this` argument in your handler as exhibited in the question text and you need to add a second argument to accept the event in and move the type hint to it (and probably rename the first argument to `this` for readability).

Given the fact that your code gets called at all, it would seem that JavaFX is happy to call a handler without passing it the event at all if it doesn't care about it (as evidenced by not having a formal parameter corresponding to it).

The type hint's only purpose is to allow the Clojure compiler to avoid emitting reflective code when `ActionEvent` methods are called on `event`. This will not prevent passing an object of a different type to the function.

Comment: Interesting, almost (?) worked.  I get this when I click the button: `Caused by: clojure.lang.ArityException: Wrong number of args (1) passed to: ClojureExampleController$-handleSubmitButtonAction`.  I also tried using `&args` as the argument and printed `(count args)` and it just returned 1.  So somehow clojure thinks it's getting one argument.

Comment: That means it is getting one argument. You'll have to convince JavaFX to pass in the other one. Or else you can look into what the "Use a Scripting Language to Handle Events" section of the tutorial suggests and just wire a Clojure function as the handler. (Note the tutorial mentions Clojure in that section as one of the language which can be used in this way.)

Comment: One more thing: Clojure supports annotations in `definterface` (on the interface itself), `deftype` and `defrecord` (on the created types and their fields and methods) and `gen-class` (on the class itself, its constructors and methods). See https://gist.github.com/richhickey/377213 for examples (the Gist includes no `gen-class` examples, as annotations support in `gen-class` wasn't available then; it works pretty much in the same way though -- you add the annotations as metadata on the appropriate name; NB. this will be the name in the `gen-class` spec, not the `defn`).

Comment: This same trick didn't work on the java side, however, as using `(Object... args)` for argument declaration caused `Controller method "handleSubmitButtonAction" not found.`  I guess javafx expects a specific method declaration, and can't use var args.  In any case, I'm after the Text object tagged by `#actiontarget`.  I suppose there is a way to use the event object and traverse the tree up and then down again searching for the element.

Comment: Thanks, again for the suggestions.  I saw the annotations github page, but it's still over my head.  And yes I also saw the comment about using javafx with "scripting" languages like clojure.  I'll figure it out eventually! :)